# Python runs a if-case that it should not!

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, case, while-loop

I have this code:

```
def random_answerlist(self):
    self.li = []
    self.winning_button = random.randint(0, 3)
    i = 0
    while i < 20 and len(self.li) is not 4:
        if i == self.winning_button:
            self.li.append(self.flags[self.current_flag][0])
        else:
            new_value = self.random_value()
            if self.flags[new_value][0] not in self.li:
                self.li.append(self.flags[new_value][0])
        i += 1
    return self.li
```

The only problem with it is that the first if-case may happen several times which should be impossible. I have searched for a good explanation to this and I can't find any.

Oh, I know the code isn't the best. But I'm kind of new to python (just a month or so) and thought this might work, but it didn't!

Do you guys know why? =)

Comment: What evidence do you have that the first if-case executes several times?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `is not` instead of `!=`?

Comment: No, there is not. I've changed it now. Thanks for the advice! But what's the main difference between "is not" and "!="?

Comment: `You couldn't solve it since I didn't post the whole code.` Great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One glaring problem is the usage of `is not` for a value comparision against `len(self.li)`. The tests `is not` and `!=` are not the same. `is` tests for identity (are these references to the same object?), `!=` tests for equality (do these objects have the same value?).

Change your `while` to:

```
while i < 20 and len(self.li) != 4:
```

Does that address the issue?

Comment: It wasn't the main problem. But I guess it'll help me anyway. Thank you very much for your reply. I didn't exactly know the difference between "is not" and "!=" which made me choose "is not" since I am kind of stressed out ;)

Comment: I will point out that, if I remember correctly, integers from -5 to 256 (inclusive, and don't ask me why they chose that range) are cached singleton objects in Python. So for integers in that range, `==` and `is` (or `!=` and `is not`) always return the same result. Of course, it's still good general practice to use `==` or `!=`, but it wouldn't make the difference in this question.

Comment: Ok I will try to remember that. But I guess I won't use it that much (right now anyway). It's always nice to learn something new like that. I noticed it worked since it didn't address a problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sorry.

I were out smoking when I realized I were the one failing:

The problem is not the if-case as you guys stated. The problem is that the else case generates randomly from the same list as the first if-case does. And then the same value is getting into the list sometimes as the one in the first if-case.

You couldn't solve it since I didn't post the whole code.

Well thanks anyway :)